# Can I use an unlicensed font that is not sold anywhere?

Tags: legal, fonts

The designers I work with have a host of fonts installed on their computers, dating to 10+ years ago. Unfortunately, since that time, they completely lost whatever license files they may have had (and I have no idea if they ever *were* licensed).

These days, they still occasionally use these random, old fonts. When I can find the font names on pay sites (like fonts.com or fontspring.com), I try to get the designers to find a safe substitute on Google Fonts, Font Squirrel, or TypeKit.

To date, I have run across two fonts they have used which, to my knowledge, were *not* being sold anywhere, and had no license of any sort. These are "Paintstroke" and "Braddon". Both are offered by various places as free downloads (wink, wink).

Both font files carry a copyright (in the file properties) that mentions "enStep Incorporated", and give dates of 1997 (Braddon) and 1996 (Paintstroke).

Is there any risk in using these fonts on a website?

Comment: Do the fonts belong to http://www.enstep.com/contact-us/ ? It would be worthwhile to shoot them an email.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I don't think so. From their about page: "Founded in 2001, Enstep Technology Solutions is a technology business partner". The font files I have were created in the mid 90s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be real headache for you if you were contacted by a lawyer who bought for a penny all copyrights from this defunct company and makes quick money as copyright troll.

My opinion: There are so many beautiful free fonts - why use such outdated stuff with non-transparent copyright situation?

Comment: Totally agree about beautiful free fonts....but the designers are picky about fonts (but not about licensing, apparently).

Comment: in germany, where i'm located, copyright issue can be pretty painful - designers should be aware more about copyright as about font face